# Retrieve Memos off ipod

Tags: ipod, virtual-memory, voice-memo

I have recorded a memo and while I was recording it. The iPod died. When I turned it on it show I taped something by show 0 minutes. I try to share and it says file is 2.7mb but won't let me share and I can't hear it. How do I retrieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% on this but I think you can use something like this software called [iBrowse](http://www.ibrowseapp.com/) that will allow you to view files from your Mac or PC. Assuming the recording is not somewhere in the restricted portion of the file structure, you can get it from there. The file should be .AAC format.

Another way, again assuming you have access to where it was saved, is to use disk mode to browse the files. Apple has a nice support page on that so I won't elaborate: [Disk Mode](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201544)

Hope that helps!